# Cadastrar/Exibir Lista C#

Tags: c#

A função deste código é ler as informações : Nome da disciplina,4 notas e a média

O problema : Não consigo transportar os dados em uma Lista no Formulário `Cadastrar` e mostrar as informações no Formulário `Exibir`.

Formulários :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do Formulário `Menu` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimuladorFMM
{
    public partial class Menu : Form
    {
        public Menu()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cadastrarMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Cadastro abrirCadastro = new Cadastro();
             abrirCadastro.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void botaoExibir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Exibir abrirExibir = new Exibir();
           abrirExibir.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Código do Formulário de `Cadastro` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimuladorFMM
{
    public partial class Cadastro : Form
    {
        public Cadastro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void finalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Disciplina> dados = new List<Disciplina>();
            Disciplina entrada = new Disciplina();
            entrada.nome = nomeCadastro.Text;
            entrada.nota[0] = Convert.ToDouble(nota1.Text);
            entrada.nota[1] = Convert.ToDouble(nota2.Text);
            entrada.nota[2] = Convert.ToDouble(nota3.Text);
            entrada.nota[3] = Convert.ToDouble(nota4.Text);
            entrada.media = (entrada.nota[0] + entrada.nota[1] + entrada.nota[2] + entrada.nota[3]) / 4;
            dados.Add(entrada);
        }
    }
}
```

Código do Formulário `Exibir` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimuladorFMM
{
    public partial class Exibir : Form
    {
        int i = 0;
        public Exibir()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Exibir_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void proximo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i < dados.Count)
            {
                i++;
                exibirNome.Text = dados[i].nome;
                exibirNota1.Text = dados[i].nota[0].ToString();
                exibirNota2.Text = dados[i].nota[1].ToString();
                exibirNota3.Text = dados[i].nota[2].ToString();
                exibirNota4.Text = dados[i].nota[3].ToString();
                exibirMedia.Text = dados[i].media.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void anterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                i--;
                exibirNome.Text = dados[i].nome;
                exibirNota1.Text = dados[i].nota[0].ToString();
                exibirNota2.Text = dados[i].nota[1].ToString();
                exibirNota3.Text = dados[i].nota[2].ToString();
                exibirNota4.Text = dados[i].nota[3].ToString();
                exibirMedia.Text = dados[i].media.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: onde você cria o **array** dados na classe **Exibir**?

Comment: Não foi criado, justamente porque queria acessar a lista do outro formulário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua classe `Cadastro`, torne a lista `estática`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimuladorFMM
{
public partial class Cadastro : Form
{
    public Cadastro()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static public List<Disciplina> dados = new List<Disciplina>();//Cria a lista estática
    private void finalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Disciplina entrada = new Disciplina();
        entrada.nome = nomeCadastro.Text;
        entrada.nota[0] = Convert.ToDouble(nota1.Text);
        entrada.nota[1] = Convert.ToDouble(nota2.Text);
        entrada.nota[2] = Convert.ToDouble(nota3.Text);
        entrada.nota[3] = Convert.ToDouble(nota4.Text);
        entrada.media = (entrada.nota[0] + entrada.nota[1] + entrada.nota[2] + entrada.nota[3]) / 4;
        dados.Add(entrada);
    }
}
}
```

E como a lista pertence á classe `Cadastro` para acessar a lista tenque mudar de `dados[index]` para `Cadastro .dados[index]`:

```
    private void proximo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i < Cadastro.dados.Count)
        {
            i++;
            exibirNome.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nome;
            exibirNota1.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[0].ToString();
            exibirNota2.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[1].ToString();
            exibirNota3.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[2].ToString();
            exibirNota4.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[3].ToString();
            exibirMedia.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].media.ToString();
        }
    }

private void anterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            i--;
            exibirNome.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nome;
            exibirNota1.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[0].ToString();
            exibirNota2.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[1].ToString();
            exibirNota3.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[2].ToString();
            exibirNota4.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].nota[3].ToString();
            exibirMedia.Text = Cadastro.dados[i].media.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Para poder acessar variáveis e métodos de outras classes, esse método ou variável deve ser pública(`public`) e estática(`static`).
Daí para acessar em outras classes, use `nomedaclasse.metodoouvariavel`.

Comment: Error CS0052 Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'List<Disciplina>' is less accessible than field 'Cadastro.dados' ?

Comment: Você botou o public depois de `static`?

Comment: Sim, static public List<Disciplina> dados = new List<Disciplina>();

Comment: Claro, tenque botar o Cadastro.dados no void proximo_Click também. Veja a resposta, que eu editei.

Comment: fiz isso, porém o erro continua

Comment: A lista está sendo criada dentro ou fora da void finalizar_Click?

Comment: foi criada  fora

Comment: Olha, no meu deu certo, funcionou, verifica se o código está igual ao da resposta. Em qual linha, de qual classe está dando erro?

Comment: O problema era a classe que não era public, agora funciona